# Why do two answers appear here in Sequence and series

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometric-progressions

The question goes like this , The sum of first three terms of a GP is 13/12 and their product is -1
Find the common ratio and terms of the GP

My answer went something like this :
Assume 3 numbers to be a , ar , ar^2
where a is the first term and r is the common ratio
Now as per question
a^3.r^3=-1
and hence a=-1/r
When I substitute this in the first condition i get:
a(1+r+r^2)=13/12
after simplification
-1/r- 1- 1/r=13/12
then I get r=-24/25 and terms to be 24/25 , -1 , 25/24

Here is how my book answer went
They assumed the terms to be a/r then a then ar
So product yielded them a^3=-1 and a=-1
and r was -3/4 or -4/3 after solving the Condition

Now why is my answer and their answer not the same ?
Is it because cancelling r rules out the possibilities of including 0 to the term but they have also done the same thing cancelling the r to get a value in first place, or is the book at fault for not considering this answer.
I am very perplexed

Comment: In the first sentence, you say that the product is $1$.  In the second paragraph, you write $a^3r^3 = -1$.  Why the change in sign?

Comment: ah sorry the question meant -1

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: i will try to look into it thank you @XanderHenderson

Comment: This is because you made a mistake.
$a(1+r+r^2)=\frac{13}{12}$ does not lead to $-\frac1r-1-\frac1r=\frac{13}{12}\cdot$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your strategy for finding the answer is just as good as the one in the book. Your answer is not the same because, at some point, you simplified an expression incorrectly.

If $a = -\frac1r$ and $a(1 + r + r^2) = \frac{13}{12}$, then after substituting, we *should* get
$$
   -\frac1r(1+r+r^2) = \frac{13}{12} \implies -\frac1r - 1 - r = \frac{13}{12}
$$
which still has the same solutions $r = -\frac34$ and $r = - \frac43$. Getting $-\frac1r - 1 - \frac1r = \frac{13}{12}$ instead is where your solution goes wrong.

We can also check that $\frac{24}{25},-1,\frac{25}{24}$ has sum $\frac{601}{600}$, not $\frac{13}{12}$.

Comment: oh , thank you so much for pointing out the mistake !